# How can I access an element of a bit-field structure in C at runtime?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I have a structure coloring with bit fields defined in C, and one such structure called color

```
struct coloring {
    unsigned int a : 3;
    unsigned int b : 3;
    unsigned int c : 3;
    unsigned int d : 3;
    unsigned int e : 3;
    unsigned int f : 3;
   ...
    unsigned int v : 3;
};
void main(){
struct coloring color;
}
```

I want to access and possibly edit a certain element, depending on rules extraneous to this specific question. During the running time, I figure out which element I want to ask and let `char letter =` the letter corresponding to the element I want. **How do I get from the letter corresponding to the element I want to the value of that element of the structure?**

I cannot use `output=color.letter` as the structure has no element named 'letter' rather an element of the field with the same name as the value of letter. I could use something like

```
if (letter=='a') {output = color.a}
if (letter=='b') {output = color.b}
...many lines...
if (letter=='v') {output=color.v}
```

But I would like a better way. I have looked for ways using pointers but I do not think they work since I am using bit fields. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You're storing a color as 22 separate 3-bit fields? RGB is three fields, RGBA is four. What sort of terrifying color format are you using here? Bitfields aside, a 22-field struct is nothing to be proud of to begin with. Are you sure you didn't mean to use an array here?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something like [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), where you can access individual bits by index. Combining three neighboring bits into an integer is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `main` should be declared `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, not `void main()`.

Comment: You'll need a selector that's either a free-standing function or a member function.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am using 7 colors to color the edges of a graph. I was hoping to compact the data I was storing for each separate edge coloring. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My apologies, thank you for letting me know, I will exercise your recommendation while tagging in the future. Thanks also for the help for the main part.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the suggestion, I will make sure to look into this! I really appreciate it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not provide dynamic selection of bit-fields or structure members. Your practical choices are generally to write your own access routines to select a field, likely using a `switch` rather than a series of `if` statements, or to manipulate the bits using bit-shift operators such as `<<`, `>>`, `&`, and `|`.